# Does std::string need a hash function when used with unordered_sets?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using an unordered set of std::strings. What is the recommended way to specify the hash function for it? Currently it is using the default. Do I need to specify one explicitly which could perform better?

Comment: You _could_ specify another one explicitly, which may or may not perform better, but you certainly don't _need_ to. What is your real question here?

Comment: question is - whether the default works well for std::string

Comment: One would certainly hope so! Otherwise, why would the compiler vendor ship it with their standard library?

Answer (score 1):

The standard specialization for `std::string` is probably good enough (probably even extremely good) for strings in general. But if your working with string of a very specific format, you probably could find or design a better algorithm for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to provide your own. If you're using VS 2010 the hash function for `std::string` is in the `xfunctional` header file included by `<functional>` if you want to take a look for yourself about whether it would meet your needs:

```
template<>
    class hash<_STD string>
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [wiki](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) , where you can see that in order to specify the hash function you should write something like :

```
 std::unordered_map<X,int,hash_X> my_map;
```

where hash_X is the definition of the hash function.

For completeness I include the code of the definition found in the [wiki](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

```
struct X{int i,j,k;};

struct hash_X{
  size_t operator()(const X &x){
    return hash<int>()(x.i) ^ hash<int>()(x.j) ^ hash<int>()(x.k);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out how to add the little comment under an answer...I would prefer to post this under Michael Burr's answer. Anyway, c++11 has `std::hash<string>` as a part of the library. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) you can view all the supported hash functions.